# Header not extending to the top/side edges of browser. Can't use absolute position

Tags: css, html

I am creating my own website. Making my own header + navbar with an unordered list.

The issue that I have is that the header is NOT extending to the edges of the browser. The only way that this works is to use in the css "header".

```
position:absolute;
```

I do not wish to use absolute positioning, but wish to keep my header at the very top.

**Is this "padding" along the header due to browser defaults? (Could a CSS reset fix it?)**

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="certscss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>




<body>
<header>
<h2>My website!</h2>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="aboutme.html">About Me </a></li>
        <li> <a href="accomplishments.html">Accomplishments </a></li>
        <li class="activemenutab"> <a href="certs.html">Certifications and Skills </a></li>
        <li> <a href="extra.html">Extracirriculars </a></li>
        <li> <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio </a></li>
        <li> <a href="contact.html">Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

<h3>Certifications and Skills</h3>




    <footer>
          &copy; Mywebsite 2015
    </footer>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";



html {
    background-color:#B5B5B5
}

header { 
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0;
    top:0;
}

h2 {
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#d9d9d9;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 2.8em;
    margin:0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none; /* takes symbols away from unordered list */
    margin:0; /* shifts ul up against h2, and shifts it up in the header box */
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
    font-family:Baskerville, serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:center; /* centers nav bar */
    font-size:0; /* this takes away the default white spaces at the end of the <li>...have to resize font in li */
}

li {
    display:inline-block; /* makes nav go horizontal */
    font-size:14px; /* size of navbar text ... !important has to be in px because ul has font size = 0*/
}

li:hover {
    background:#000000; /* changes tab to black */
    color:#E09635; /* changes text to color */
    transition-duration: 0.3s; /* response time on navbar icon hover */
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0; /* zero delay to have transtion occur */
}

a {
    text-decoration:none; /*removes underline from a links */
    color:inherit; /* takes color from parent, in this case, li */
    display:block; /* makes the a box relatable to li */
    padding: 10px;  /* creates padding around a box for navbar and adds to clickable region because of anchor */
}

.activemenutab { /* this is the class used to make the one you are on highlighted ... needs to be swithched in html */
    background-color:#EDEDED;
    color:#E09635;
}

/* ---------- body below */

h3 {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Baskerville, serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    word-spacing: 0.5em;
}

/* ---------- footer below */

footer {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#EDEDED;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
    padding:.2em;
}
```

CONCLUSION!: How do I get my header to extend to the edges of the browser (on the top, the left, and the right), similar to my FOOTER, WITHOUT using absolute positioning. Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset your css:
Like:

```
/*
*  html5 doctor css reset | http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet
*/
html,body,div,span,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,abbr,address,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,samp,small,strong,sub,sup,var,b,i,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}
body{line-height:1}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}
nav ul{list-style:none}
blockquote,q{quotes:none}
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none}
a{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}
ins{background-color:#ff9;color:#000;text-decoration:none}
mark{background-color:#ff9;color:#000;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold}
del{text-decoration:line-through}
abbr[title],dfn[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;cursor:help}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
hr{display:block;height:1px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #ccc;margin:1em 0;padding:0}
input,select{vertical-align:middle}
```

CSS Reset: http://cssreset.com/scripts/html5-doctor-css-reset-stylesheet/

So many elements of CSS reset you don't use, but its good to reset all.

**[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ferrrmolina/3h0ywqjc/)**

Answer (score 5):

The body element has a default margin that you need to get rid of:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n1nkrhd4/)**